# Помогите оптимизировать паджинацию

Tags: wpf, оптимизация, filter, paging

Выполняю фильтрацию коллекции `CollectionViewSource`.  Использую для разбивки коллекции на страницы (аналог пейджинга из веба). Собственно разбивку осуществляю с помощью

```
CollectionViewSource.Filter = viewData_Filter.
```

Код события такой:

```
void viewData_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = ((Product)e.Item).TmpId;

        if ((index >= ItemsPerPage * CurrentPage) && (index < ItemsPerPage * (CurrentPage + 1)))
        {
            e.Accepted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Accepted = false;
        }
    }
```

Здесь `ItemsPerPage` устанавливается при инициализации приложения, `CurrentPage` и `index` - меняется во время выполнения программы. Может есть идеи как оптимизировать, а то больно уж долго происходит подготовка отображения?

Answer (score 1):

Посидел, подумал. А все ведь оказывается просто. Зачем я полез в дебри? Может хотел найти готовое решение... А оно получилось избыточным. Хотя это еще надо проверить, может все не зря... Собственно вот, что мне сейчас пришло в голову по поводу самодельного пейджинга:
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Name="lvList"
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"/>
        <TextBox Name="tbPage"
                 Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="517" TextChanged="tbPage_TextChanged"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string> collection;
    List<string> items;
    int pageLength = 50;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // инициализировали коллекцию
        items = new List<string>();
        for (int i=0; i< 10000; i++)
        {
            items.Add("Строка номер " + i);
        }
        ChangePage(0);
    }

    public void ChangePage(int pageNum)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        result = new List<string>(items.Skip(pageNum * pageLength));
        result = new List<string>(result.Take(pageLength));

        collection = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>(result);
        lvList.ItemsSource = collection;
    }

    private void tbPage_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int page = 1;
        if (Int32.TryParse(tbPage.Text, out page))
        {
            ChangePage(page);
        }
    }
}
```

Только придется переписывать всю логику приложения, если делать так. Что думаете?

Comment: Зависит от. Если паджинация нужна в одном месте — отличное решение. Если в нескольких — можно будет удавиться из-за копипасты.

Comment: Это как пример. Естественно в боевом варианте всю логику нужно упаковать в класс и пользоваться уже на уровне объектов. В общем за выходные попробую свое приложение перевести на эти рельсы. О результатах отпишу. Может в будущем кому-то пригодится. А то я по данной теме маловато информации нашел в интернете.

Comment: Ну, вы переизобретёте CollectionView, по сути. Сделать-то можно, но зачем?

Comment: Данный вариант должен быстрее работать, потому что не лопатит всю коллекцию, проверяя условие у каждого айтема, а выбирает четко нужный диапазон и его возвращает. Назову QuickCollectionView :D

Comment: `PagingCollectionView` делает абсолютно то же самое.

Comment: Я набредал на него, но из-за того, что он приделан к сильверлайту не смог им воспользоваться. По-моему это в т.ч. было связано с тем, что я решил использовать целевую платформу .NET 3.5. Чтоб у большего числа людей оно запускалось без установки компонентов, непонятных для них.

Comment: Я про класс из примера, на который я сослался в своём ответе.

Answer (score 0):

На большом StackOverflow есть пример паджинации с помощью своего класса `CollectionView`. Не могу сказать, какой код будет работать быстрее, но попробовать стоит.

```
public class PagingCollectionView : CollectionView
{
    private readonly IList _innerList;
    private readonly int _itemsPerPage;

    private int _currentPage = 1;

    public PagingCollectionView(IList innerList, int itemsPerPage)
        : base(innerList)
    {
        this._innerList = innerList;
        this._itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (this._currentPage < this.PageCount) // page 1..n-1
            {
                return this._itemsPerPage;
            }
            else // page n
            {
                var itemsLeft = this._innerList.Count % this._itemsPerPage;
                if (0 == itemsLeft)
                {
                    return this._itemsPerPage; // exactly itemsPerPage left
                }
                else
                {
                    // return the remaining items
                    return itemsLeft;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int CurrentPage
    {
        get { return this._currentPage; }
        set
        {
            this._currentPage = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentPage"));
        }
    }

    public int ItemsPerPage { get { return this._itemsPerPage; } }

    public int PageCount
    {
        get 
        { 
            return (this._innerList.Count + this._itemsPerPage - 1) 
                / this._itemsPerPage; 
        }
    }

    private int EndIndex
    {
        get
        {
            var end = this._currentPage * this._itemsPerPage - 1;
            return (end > this._innerList.Count) ? this._innerList.Count : end;
        }
    }

    private int StartIndex
    {
        get { return (this._currentPage - 1) * this._itemsPerPage; }
    }

    public override object GetItemAt(int index)
    {
        var offset = index % (this._itemsPerPage); 
        return this._innerList[this.StartIndex + offset];
    }

    public void MoveToNextPage()
    {
        if (this._currentPage < this.PageCount)
        {
            this.CurrentPage += 1;
        }
        this.Refresh();
    }

    public void MoveToPreviousPage()
    {
        if (this._currentPage > 1)
        {
            this.CurrentPage -= 1;
        }
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Полный код примера и описание можете найти в вопросе "[How can I paginate a WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974872)"

Comment: Взял код из статьи по ссылке, потестировал с  коллекцией в 1000, 10000 и 100000 элементов. В указанном коде падения скорости от увеличения числа элементов не заметил. Но все равно переключает не мгновенно. То есть задержка есть и ощутимая... И все же спасибо, можно будет попробовать прикрутить к моей программе этот подход. Может что и изменится. Может еще у кого есть варианты?

Comment: @AlexanderSmirnov Возможно, узкое место не там, где вы ищете. Попробуйте оставить от дата-темплейтов пустышки и посмотреть, в паджинации ли проблема.